# Conditional formatting using OR() ignores one of the arguments

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to colour the data in one column based on data in another column.

What is wrong with the following formula?

```
=OR($D1 = "TEXT 1", SEARCH("TEXT 2", $D1) > 0)
```

What I would like to do here is "colour the cell when it is exactly `TEXT 1` or `TEXT 2` is a part of its value".

When I do this, it only validates the argument within the `SEARCH()` and not `TEXT 1`, but I know the first is correct because if I remove the `SEARCH()` as an argument, then it validates `TEXT 1` (even inside the `OR()`).

What am I missing here?

Also, if there is a better way to do the `TEXT 2` validation, I would appreciate knowing about it. I reaaaaly dislike Excel's syntax. A validation similar to SQL's "LIKE", a function called "CONTAINS", or something like that, would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `TEXT 2` is not found the SEARCH will error and as such the whole OR will error and will be seen as FALSE regardless of whether D1 = `Text 1`

Use ISNUMBER to return FALSE or TRUE:

```
=OR($D1 = "TEXT 1", ISNUMBER(SEARCH("TEXT 2", $D1)))
```

[image]

Comment: wait, really? I was sure that `> 0` would make it return a boolean. BTW, I thought `SEARCH` always returned a number. What is happening here? It did indeed work (Confused programmer having to work for the first time with Excel)

Comment: SEARCH will return a number if found and `#Value` error if not found.  In VBA `Instr` will return `0` if not found, but not the worksheet functions.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you very much, Scott. I guess my problem was the inability to visualize when errors occur and not expecting that an error could actually be a return value.